# Solving an ode numerically in matlab

Tags: matlab, ode

I understand the logic of the numerical solving, that matlab starts with a value for your unknown, and loops until the equation converges to a value. However what I don't understand is the proper way to enter my equation. I think that using the `ode45` function is the best way to do this. I have the following equation `U^(n+1) = U^n - (t'*3250/10)-(t'/2)(.004(v^n)^2/10`.
I have a suspicion my equation needs to be in a different form however I am unsure of the correct way to have matlab solve the equation.

I tried entering the equation in matlab as is, however it complains that v and n are unknown variables and I am unsure of how to handle those. The final goal of solving this equation is to find the value for v.

```
C=@(t,v) u^n-(3250*t'/10)-(t'/2)*((.004*(v^n)^2)/10)
[t,v]=ode45(C,[0,5],1)
```

produces the following errors:

```
Undefined function or variable 'u'.

Error in @(t,v)u^n-(3250*t'/10)-(t'/2)*((.004*(u^n)^2)/10)


Error in odearguments (line 88)
f0 = feval(ode,t0,y0,args{:});   % ODE15I sets args{1} to yp0.

Error in ode45 (line 114)
{neq, tspan, ntspan, next, t0, tfinal, tdir, y0, f0, odeArgs, odeFcn, ...

Error in ae301_3 (line 2)
[t,v]=ode45(C,[0,5],1)
```

Comment: Uh, what function / toolbox are you using to do the solving?   Check its documentation?

Comment: `ode45`http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html Documentation has examples that are not helpful in my situation

Comment: So, show us your code.   I suspect you're not declaring your function correctly.

Comment: What are `u^n`, `v^n`, and `t'` supposed to be? Is that your attempt to translate equations or [recurrence relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Relationship_to_differential_equations)? What about the documentation is unclear? You might also read through this [MathWorks blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/06/10/from-symbolic-differential-equations-to-their-numeric-solution/).

Comment: Your understanding of the logic of ODE solving is incorrect. Matlab's `ode45` uses a one-step Runge-Kutta method. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_methods_for_ordinary_differential_equations for a background on such methods. You will need to provide more information about the variables in your problem, particularly `u`, `n` and `t'`.

Answer (score 0):

ode solvers are used of Ordinary Differential Equations. Your equation is not differential but it is a non linear algebraic equation.
In Matlab you can solve it using fzero. However your function can be easily rearranged to be explicit and can be solved analytically without any iterative procedure.